# Insert data using Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

i am using following written code to insert bulk data using core data technique...
Please tell me is it right approach to do the same...I am taking context and entity object inside the loop...if taken outside only last element of arrays gets inserted...Please advise...

```
DataGetSet *objDataGetSet=nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *context=nil;

for(int i=0;i<[arrTemp count];i++)
{
  context = [obj_delegate managedObjectContext];

  NSManagedObject *propertyInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Property" 
                   inManagedObjectContext:context];

  objDataGetSet=[arrTemp objectAtIndex:i];

  [propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet code] forKey:@"Code"];
  [propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet location] forKey:@"Location"];
  [propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet ownershipType] forKey:@"OwnershipType"];
  [propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet price] forKey:@"Price"];
  [propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet propertyType] forKey:@"PropertyType"];
  [propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet size] forKey:@"Size"];  
}
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thats correct. But it could be better:

First of all, it's not that good to take manageObjectContext from appDelegate. You can pass it to your rooViewController class manually from AppDelegate's method, for example like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    if ( !managedObjectContext_ )
    {
       [self createManagedObjectContext]; // you should write this method(create and insert your enities)
    }

    self.yourRootViewControllerClass.managedObjectContext_ = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.yourRootViewControllerClass;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Then (if you have sub ViewControllers) you have to pass your managedObjectContext from your rootViewController class in the same manner like from AppDelegate.

One more thing is that you can make a managedObject subclass, and then you'll be able to get and set properties in an easier manner (not `[propertyInfo setValue:[objDataGetSet code] forKey:@"Code"]` but just `propertyInfo.Code = [objDataGetSet code]`
You can read about how-to do it clearly [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take managedObjectContext inside a loop, you can take it outside.
But anyway, even if you do it the way you do, it should insert exactly [arrTemp count] entities for sure, may be your problem in that arrTemp array?

And are you sure, you check the count of inserted objects correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i am able to insert the objects...i am getting all 118 rows in the sqlite file...i just wanted to sure is it right approach to insert bulk data??

Comment: hi there...i am fetching the results for a particular row...say for row number 5...internally in a sqlite file i am seeing a row having field name Z_PK...i am trying to make use of this field in my NSPredicate but since its not in my entity(generates automatically) i am getting crash...so is there any way to access any particular row without adding any field which keeps track of rows...